# How to build cross-IDE java GUI's using "interface builders"?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, intellij-idea, visual-editor

In a Java project with developers that use different IDEs, say Eclipse and IntelliJ, what's the best way of developing visual components using the tools offered by the IDEs ("[Visual Editor Project](http://eclipse.org/vep/)" for Eclipse and "[Swing GUI Designer](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gui_builder.html)" for IntelliJ)?

If a developer using Eclipse needs to make changes to a GUI written by another developer in IntelliJ (and vice versa) he will have quite a hard time and maybe even make the code incompatible with the original tool that built it.

Is there a solution or do all developer just need to use the same tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 solutions:

- Don't use GUI design tools at all, code the UI code by hand
- Use a plug-in available for most of the IDEs (such as [JFormDesigner](http://www.formdev.com/))